# Qualtrics (Javascript) - Matrix table - replace text entry fields with drop down list

Tags: javascript, matrix, qualtrics

In Qualtrics I currently have a short text entry version of a "Matrix Table"-question. Let's say it is a 5*5-Matrix. Instead of having 25 text entry fields I would prefer 25 fields offering a drop down list with answer choices. Unfortunately, there is not such a question type available in Qualtrics. Does anyone know if it is possible to replace the text entry fields by dropdown list using Javascript (or if there are any other solutions)?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a Side-by-Side question instead, which can be formatted as a 5x5 table of drop down menus.  You can hide the additional column headings if desired.

Comment: Thank you. That works excellent. Never used side-by-side question before.

Comment: The only negative to this is the lack of mobile capability for side-by-side questions.